# Linked List Program is crashing again and again

Tags: c, linked-list

I have made a sorted linked list program. I don't know why, but it is crashing again and again. Tried to fix it but, didn't work. The problem seems to be in a print_list function, but don't know what's the problem.
here's my code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node{
    struct node *next;
    int val;
};

struct LLADT{

    struct node *head;
};

void init(struct LLADT *LL){
    LL-> head = 0;

}

// Printing a linked list
void print_list(struct LLADT *LL){
    struct node *temp;
    temp = LL-> head;
    while(temp ->next!=NULL){  // changed temp!=NULL to temp->next!=NULL
        printf("%d\n", temp->val);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}

//inserting sorted elements
void sortInsert(struct LLADT *LL, int num){

    struct node *newNode;
    newNode->val = num;
    newNode->next = 0;
    newNode =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));


    // Case -1: List is empty

    if(LL->head == 0){
        LL->head = newNode;

    }
    else{

        struct node *curr;
        curr = LL->head;
        struct node *prev;
        prev = NULL;

    // Traversing list to find the insert location
        while(curr != 0){
            if(curr->val >= newNode->val){
                break;
            }

            else{

                prev = curr;
                curr = curr -> next;
            }

        // Case-2:
            if(curr == LL->head){
                newNode->next = LL->head;
                LL->head = newNode;

            }
            // case-3
            else{

                newNode->next = curr;
                prev->next = newNode;
            }

        }

    }
}

int main(){
struct LLADT LL;
    sortInsert(&LL,17);
    sortInsert(&LL,3);
    sortInsert(&LL,5);
    sortInsert(&LL,2);
    sortInsert(&LL,1);
    sortInsert(&LL,20);

    //print_list(&LL);

getch();
return 0;

}
```

using codeblocks.

Comment: you should check your `newNode = malloc(...)` to make sure `newNode` isn't NULL. Also, `curr` isn't initialized, so `while(curr != 0)` is undefined behavior. `curr->val` must surely segfault.

Comment: Both `while(curr != 0)` and `if(curr->val >= newNode->val)` are used before anything is assigned to `curr`. Your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: what should i initialize, curr with? to make this program work.

Comment: `head`. To traverse a linked list, start at `head` and iterate until you get to NULL

Comment: I did this actually, but still crashing

Comment: update your question with your latest code

Comment: @Sami firstly I would like to know how are you using conio.h on codeblocks IDE. **:D**

Comment: @NeoR it's just for show :D

Comment: @Sami yeah right so I guess that getch()  is also just for show.

Comment: I would suggest that you provide absolutely correct information cause codeblock IDE genrally use the gcc compiler which is also the default compiler and does not have the conio. h header file.

Comment: I am using visual studio at the same time too, it's giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node{
   struct node *next;
   int val;
};

  /*struct LLADT{

  struct node *head;
 };*/
struct node * head ;

void init(){
 head = NULL;

}

 // Printing a linked list
 void print_list(){
 struct node *temp;
 temp =  head;
 while(temp !=NULL){
     printf("%d\n", temp->val);
     temp = temp -> next;
 }
 }

 //inserting sorted elements
  void sortInsert(int num){

  struct node *newNode;
  struct node *curr;
  newNode =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->val = num;
  newNode->next = NULL;

 // Case -1: List is empty

  if(head == NULL){
      head = newNode;

    }
 else{

    curr=head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL){
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    curr->next=newNode;

  // Traversing list to find the insert location
 //        while(curr != NULL){
 //          if(curr->val >= newNode->val){
 //            break;
   //      }

    //    else{

      //      prev = curr;
        //    curr = curr -> next;
       // }

    // Case-2:
       // if(curr == LL->head){
         //   newNode->next = LL->head;
          //  LL->head = newNode;

        //}
        // case-3
        //else{

          //  newNode->next = curr;
           // prev->next = newNode;
       // }

    //}

    }
    }

   int main(){
   //struct LLADT LL;
     sortInsert(17);
     sortInsert(3);
     sortInsert(5);
     sortInsert(2);
     sortInsert(1);
     sortInsert(20);

     print_list(head);

    getch();
    return 0;
   }
```

You can try this code as there is no need to declare other `struct` for head

Commented out your unwanted code

Comment: It's printing but it's not in ascending order, or sorted

Comment: Now you can change the conditions based on the value of the `node->val` and `num` and sort the link list accordingly

Comment: I didn't understand, can you edit your code to show me?